# Converting xml to another form of xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

im having trouble converting a xml file 
I had a SOAP request and i want to convert it to normal tags

```
e.g.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-
ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://testnamespace.org">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetUserBalance>
<ns1:userId>tonysin</ns1:userId>
<ns1:currency>CNY</ns1:currency>
</ns1:GetUserBalance>
<ns1:loginToken>a1b2c3d4</ns1:loginToken>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

to

```
<GetUserBalance>
   <userId>tonysin</userId>
   <currency>CNY</currency>
</GetUserBalance>
<loginToken>a1b2c3d4</loginToken>
```

Comment: Have you tried to write some xslt ? anything !? show us

Comment: Sorry, ive managed to done it using. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to done it with this xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://testnamespace.org">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//SOAP-ENV:Body/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```